# what is limit of the function $f(x)$ at $+\infty$?

Tags: limits, functions

$f(x)=\sqrt{x+3} \sin(\sqrt{x+3}-\sqrt{x+1})$ I just cant find a way to solve it i tried using squeeze theorem .
thanks in advance

Comment: I reckon that $\sqrt{x+3}-\sqrt{x+1}\sim x^{-1/2}$ as $x\to0$.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align*}
f(x)=\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{x+1}}\right)}{\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{x+1}}}\cdot\dfrac{2\sqrt{x+3}}{\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{x+1}}\rightarrow 1.
\end{align*}

Comment: thank you so much It was so easy still I couldn't figure out